# Error installing IBM Mobile First Platform Studio 7.1.0 in Eclipse Luna (Missing requirement: Model Plug-in 8.0.0.v20150913_1242)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, eclipse-luna

Eclipse: 
-Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
-Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)

Java: 
-java version "1.8.0_25"
-Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
-Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Eclipse Java Runtime: 
-jdk1.8.0_25

Installing from this file: `MFPF_7.1_ELP_UPD_IBM_MF_STUDIO.zip`

I got this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20150913-2345 (com.ibm.imp.tools.wce.feature.feature.group 7.1.0.00-20150913-2345)
  Missing requirement: Model Plug-in 8.0.0.v20150913_1242 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.model 8.0.0.v20150913_1242) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.type.core [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Web Page Generation Core Plugin 7.2.500.v20150913_1242 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.webpage.core 7.2.500.v20150913_1242)
    To: bundle com.ibm.etools.webtools.model [8.0.0,9.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM Mobile Application Tools 7.1.0.00-20150913-2345 (com.ibm.imp.feature.feature.group 7.1.0.00-20150913-2345)
    To: com.ibm.imp.worklight.core [7.1.0.00-20150913-2345]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20150913-2345 (com.ibm.imp.tools.wce.feature.feature.group 7.1.0.00-20150913-2345)
    To: com.ibm.imp.feature.feature.group 7.1.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Core 7.1.0.00-20150913-2345 (com.ibm.imp.worklight.core 7.1.0.00-20150913-2345)
    To: bundle com.ibm.etools.webtools.webpage.core [7.2.0,8.0.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Installed in Eclipse Kepler ( Kepler Service Release 1). Works fine! :)

Answer (score 1):

Worklight and MobileFirst Platform do not support Java 8 as your requirement

download to either Java 6 or 7 and try again (make sure Eclipse is also configured to use that version JRE)

Comment: Hello, Nazmul. According documentation, IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1 is compatible with Oracle Java SDK/JRE/JDK 8.0

Comment: Here the doc link: http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=46183B706BEA11E48038141DE954FC88

Comment: Can you try the following:
a) Try installing a later studio plugin build
b) Try when there is internet connectivity

Comment: try with @VivinK Comment  . also you can try the latest available studio plugin 7.1 iFix available from IBM Fix Central

Comment: @AndreLuis if you solved this particular error then share please ?

Comment: @Nazmul, I'm sorry dude, forgot to update here, yes, i solved switching to Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: @AndreLuis could you help me to get a job on mobilefirst platform ? please help me

Comment: Hi Nazmul, I can't guarantee anything, but i will try to talk with my manager about it.